# Why stored procedure with date parameters work so slowly?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a stored procedure with 2 date parameters: @dateFrom and @dateTo. I use them in where clause:

```
where CONVERT(DATE,ModificationDate) BETWEEN @dateFrom AND @dateTo
```

Unfortunately procedure works slow. On the other hand when I use simple GETDATE()-number of days the procedure works much faster e.g:

```
where CONVERT(DATE,ModificationDate)>=GETDATE()-14
```

What's the reason? What should I change in terms of using parameters to fasten my query? Above is main reason why my query works slow, all indices are applied properly etc.

Comment: Smells like parameter sniffing

Comment: The reason why it appears to be much faster is because GETDATE() returns a time and so you're only finding rows with the exact date and time.

Comment: @JeffModen - the predicate is `>=GETDATE()-14` so that will be a 13/14 day range. They aren't doing an equality on it

Comment: @Muska - What is the datatype of `ModificationDate`? What do the execution plans look like?

Comment: @MartinSmith - crud.  Thanks.  In my still caffeine deprived state, I flat missed the > and read it as an equality. <head desk>.  Still, it makes me wonder even more why they're bothering to use CONVERT here.  If they're looking for a starting point that includes a whole day then converting GETDATE() to a midnight/00:00 time would work a whole lot better as SARGable critreria not to mention it wouldn't matter what temporal datatype the ModificationDate is.

Comment: @MartinSmith datatype is datetime. Execuction Plan said I needed to add some indices on columns, especially on ModificationDate and I did it. So no more indices to add left. I've changed parameter datatype to DATETIME instead of DATE and query works a little bit faster but much slower than GETDATE()-days

Answer (score 0):

Stored procedures have a rather complex method of compiling SQL queries.  In particular, the plan is often generated once and then re-used.  So, the initial parameter value sets the stage for subsequent calls.

In many cases, the simplest solution is to recompile the code each time, by adding `OPTION (RECOMPILE)` to the end of the query.

Note that compiling the query does add some additional overhead.  However, for many queries this is often much less than the benefit is optimizing the query to changing table sizes and parameters.

Comment: unfortunately it doesn't help

Answer (score 0):

Try to avoid data conversion in left side of the SQL condition as much as possible. Otherwise, SQL server has to convert the entire data set before evaluating the condition and which is inefficient. If you are trying to ignore the time part of the date modify you're "where" a statement like this

Declare @dateFrom date , @dateTo date

where ModificationDate>=@dateFrom and ModificationDate<=dateadd(day,1,@dateTo)

Comment: i tried this but 'where' clause works faster with 'between ... and...' BTW I'm not converting date anymore

Comment: @AselaSampath . . . SQL Server will use indexes for conversions from `datetime` to `date`.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Casting to date is sargable, but not always a [good idea](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/34047/cast-to-date-is-sargable-but-is-it-a-good-idea)

Comment: To be clear, it's not just "the left side" nor is it just the dataconversion.  You should never encapsulate any column that's in an ON or WHERE clause in a formula.  A date conversion is an "exception" that MS recently worked in but it's still slower than not having any conversion or any formula on a column in the ON or WHERE clauses.  The important term here is SARGability.  You should do a Yabingooducklehoo on that subject.

Comment: ok, got it, thanks for tips. Btw what is Yabingooducklehoo? Cant google it

Comment: Ya = first part of "YAhoo".  bing = bing but last letter -s first letter of "goo" for "Google". Duck is for DuckDuckGo searches.  "le" is the last part of "Google".  "hoo" is the last part of "yaHOO".  It's my shorthand for "do a search using your favorite search engine" but I forget that others might not gleen what it means.

Comment: @JeffModen saving a lot of time and typing there ;)

Comment: Understood but it's misleading.  People will think that it's ok to encapsulate column names in formulas if they simply move it to the right side of the equation and that's not correct. ;)